# Android ContextMenu - nothing selected

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm developing an Android app with simple `ContextMenu` that is containing three elements. Is there any possibility to catch nothing selected event on ContextMenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding

```
public void onContextMenuClosed (Menu menu)
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsMenuClosed(android.view.Menu)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see it because I was opening context menu form fargment.